# Calculate radius based on given quantity in LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Say you have this example

```
<script>
  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  L.tileLayer('', {
    maxZoom: 18,
  }).addTo(mymap);

  L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 20,
  }).addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

As you can see the radius of the circle is 20 which looks fine. But what if you have a large data?

I'm trying to show a radius based on given number of infected people here https://the2019ncov.com

You can see that the radius for each circle are static, that is because when I set it to the number of people infected, the circle becomes really really big because each country/province can have a thousand+ infected people.

Is there a way to calculate a good radius size based on that data?

Example

1. China 2,503
2. Philippines 3
3. USA 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a statistician, but a log scale with the current numbers looks reasonable.
You can play with min and factor to get the best representation.

`min` should be non-zero since `log(1) = 0`, which would not show a circle for countries with 1 person.

```js
console.clear();

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('', {
  maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);

const data = [1, 6, 11, 16, 25, 24290]

const min = 10;
const factor = 50;
const scale = (d) => Math.floor(Math.log(d) * factor) + min;

const points = data.map(d => {
  return { d, r: scale(d) };
});

points.forEach(({d, r}, i) => {
  
  console.log(d, r);
  
  const lat = 51.508;
  const lng = -0.11 + i/100;

  L.circle([lat, lng], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: r,
  }).addTo(mymap);
  
  var myIcon = L.divIcon({html: `<p>${d}, ${r}</p>`});
  L.marker([lat-0.006, lng], { opacity: 0.3, icon: myIcon}).addTo(mymap);
});
```

```css
#mapid { height: 180px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

---

**Zoom factor for radius scaling**

My perception is that the log scale doesn't quite work so well when zooming out on the map.

One way to adjust it is the use the zoom factor (returned from the map) to adjust the scale.

Zoom ranges from 1 to 18, starting at 5.
The circles look good at 5 and above, so proportionally shrinking below 5 seems to be the way to go.

```js
scale(d) {
  const min = 1;
  const factor = 5;
  /*
    Scale down as you zoom out.
    Problem: at zoom level 2 the circles look a bit too large and crowded,
             because the map shrinks underneath, the circles should also scale down.
             Higher zooms are ok, so zoomFactor is 1 for those.
  */
  const zoomFactor = this.zoom >= 5 ? 1 : this.zoom / 10;  // adjust divisor for best optics
  return Math.floor(Math.log(d) * factor * zoomFactor) + min;
},
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. It looks very nice and reasonable. Didn't know about log scales to be honest. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. It works great! Though I used min 1 and factor 5 for now. 10 and 50 looks very big. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the feedback . Another 100 in China in the last 4 hours!

Comment: I was going to suggest (but it slipped my mind) that the `scale()` function might also need to take account of the zoom factor of the map. For instance, if you take a look at Australia, the spots get bigger relative to the continent as you zoom out. So, at the whole-world view they look disconcertingly large.

Comment: You're right. I noticed that whenever I zoom out, it gets better and better.

Comment: No, I reckon it's worse when you zoom out. The visual impression of larger dots (larger relative to the country) is greater danger, even though the numbers don't change.

Comment: Also, at full-world zoom SE Asia is just an amorphous blob. It would be worth while checking out adding the zoom factor into the mix, if you know how to feed it into the `L.circle()` method.

Comment: Yes sorry. Looks like I have to calculate also based on the zoom level.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Richard. Will leave a comment in the code that you helped me.

Comment: Hi Richard. I added you in the acknowledgments section of readme. Radius scaling now looks good with zoom factor level. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers, a nice intro to Leaflet for me.